# How can I measure the amplitude of a light wave?

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, measurements

Suppose I have a light wave and I want to measure its amplitude, or check to see if it has an amplitude of a certain value: how would one go about doing this?

Comment: Use a photodiode: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode. There are very expensive calibrated ones, but even the uncalibrated ones are useful for most purposes and they are reasonably priced (in the $1-10 range) e.g. http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay-Semiconductors/BPW20RF/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMs50KUSuyRkppKT8H8G%2fzRCzWGWT%2fd1Lmc%3d. Be aware that you are really measuring intensity ($W/m^2$) by measuring the photocurrent. If you want to measure really large areas, use a solar cell. They are basically very large photodiodes, just not as precise.

Answer (score 1):

Direct measurement of the amplitude of the optical field requires interferometric techniques.  One that works is the [FROG - Frequency Resolved Optical Grating](https://www.rp-photonics.com/frequency_resolved_optical_gating.html).  There are many variations on it today, including from the original developers: [Trebino Research Group](http://www.frog.gatech.edu/).

These devices were designed for ultrafast pulses.  For CW one usually just measures intensity and polarization, followed by a computation.