# How does amplitude affect photon's intensity as a particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, wave-particle-duality, photoelectric-effect, intensity

Considering the scenario were a photon acts as a particle, how does amplitude affect the photon?

Does it increase its intensity? How do you visualise this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the amplitude of a light wave?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/259477/what-is-the-amplitude-of-a-light-wave)

Comment: @Charlie I was looking for a more quantum-mechanics approach, especially relating to the photoelectric effect  ie- why does a photon not ionise an atom if it is below the threshold frequency even if it has very high amplitude?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a higher amplitude, just visualize more photons per unit volume (i.e., a higher number density and a higher energy density). But each individual photon has an energy that depends only on the frequency, not on the amplitude. Having lots of low-energy photons around doesn’t tend to ionize atoms if none of them have enough energy to eject an electron.

One exception to this general picture would be multi-photon ionization, but this is suppressed by factors of the fine-structure constant so it is comparatively rare.

Comment: How come it can be visualised like this (more photons per unit volume) if it's only the amplitude of a single photon that is changed?

Comment: Individual photons don’t have amplitude. They don’t “wave”. They are point particles with energy and momentum. EM waves have amplitude. Photons and EM waves are not the same thing.